# Animate the hiding of items in my sidebar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sidebar on my page. When the user resize the browser, items are showed only if they are not cut (at the bottom of the window). It works as you can see on the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/MJ9VC/23/

To test: resize the browser (make the window height smaller). You'll see some items hiding. Resize the browser (make the window height bigger). You'll seel some items showing.

**The problem**: I succeed doing the animation from **not showed** to **showed** (smoothly showing items) but I failed doing the animation from **showed** to **not showed**.

I don't know if I'm clear?

Comment: It looks to me that you only execute the animation when the element (this) is not visible. "if (that.css('visibility') != 'visible')...".

Comment: @ron I know but I didn't find a solution. You can try to adjust the jsFiddle if you have an idea... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
if (y <= itemBottom) {
    if(!that.hasClass('hidden') && !that.is(':animated')){
        that.removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden','slow'); 
    }
}
else{
    if(that.hasClass('hidden') && !that.is(':animated')){
        that.addClass('visible','slow').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

The order of adding/removing of hidden/visible is important. You also don't want to be messing with it while it's fading in/out, and you also need JQuery UI to allow you to animate the adding of a class:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/jrvsB/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from setting the visibility to hidden

```
that.css('visibility','hidden');
```

As soon as you do that it is going to disappear, regardless of the opacity you are setting.

Can you skip the whole visibility attribute and just use opacity?  So when the browser gets to small you do:

```
that.animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
```

Comment: I know that that.css('visibility','hidden'); is the problem. I already try a lot of combination without success. You can try to adjust my jsFiddle if you think of a solution... Thanks anyway.

Comment: optionally, set visibility to hidden in the callback function of `animate`. This way it will get hidden only after the animation is complete. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Mmmm tested again and it doesn't work unfortunately. I suck with css.